# Vitess: Initialize keyspace schema using SQL file

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, vitess, kubernetes-vitess

I am using helm and the file [101_initial_cluster.yaml](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/blob/master/examples/helm/101_initial_cluster.yaml) from the Vitess example to setup my initial cluster. The example has a schema initialization using SQL string as shown below:

```
schema:
        initial: |-
          create table product(
            sku varbinary(128),
            description varbinary(128),
            price bigint,
            primary key(sku)
          );
          create table customer(
            customer_id bigint not null auto_increment,
            email varbinary(128),
            primary key(customer_id)
          );
          create table corder(
            order_id bigint not null auto_increment,
            customer_id bigint,
            sku varbinary(128),
            price bigint,
            primary key(order_id)
          );
```

I would like to replace this with a file `initial: my_initial_keyspace_schema.sql`. From the Vitess documentation I can see Vitess does allow for this using  `ApplySchema -sql_file=user_table.sql user`, but I would like to initialize using the helm file.

This would be very helpful as it is very tedious to organize and paste the schema as a `string`. Tables that depend on others have to be pasted first and the rest follow. Forgetting makes Vitess throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm afraid there is no out-of-the-box feature to enable initializing DbSchema directly from SQL file in the current state of Vitess Helm chart. You can identify any of its configurable parameters via `helm inspect <chart_name>` command.

However, you can try customizing it to match your needs in following ways:

1. Stay with ApplySchema {-sql=} mode
   but let the SQL schema be slurped from static file as a part of Helm chart 
   template
    (e.g. from *static/initial_schema.sql* location):

   So just add a piece of control flow code like this one:

```html
{{ if .Values.initialSchemaSqlFile.enabled }}
        {{- $files := .Files }}
        {{- range tuple "static/initial_schema.sql" }}
        {{ $schema := $files.Get . }}
{{- end }}
{{ else }}
   # Default inline schema from Values.topology.cells.keyspaces[0].schema
{{ end }}
```

Check more on using Helm built-in Objects like File [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#glob-patterns)

2. Use ApplySchema {-sql-file=} mode
   Adapt a piece of code [here](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/blob/d4176b97bcd95072ae452c399d90e4eefe135273/helm/vitess/templates/_keyspace.tpl#L79), where vtctlclient command is constructed.
   This would require also to introduce a new Kubernetes Volume object ([nfs](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-pv.yaml) 
   or [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683594/how-to-clone-a-private-git-repository-into-a-kubernetes-pod-using-ssh-keys-in-se?noredirect=1&lq=1) repo based are good options here), which you could [mount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#example-pod-2) on 
   Job, under specific path, from where initial_schema.sql file would be used.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try them out and give feedback.